# Can pulsar geo-replicate among different release versions, for example 2.8.x and 2.7.x?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Apache Pulsar supports geo-replication between clusters in different regions. I am wondering if there are any compatibility issues between clusters running different version of Pulsar.

The question is for planning purposes, so that I know whether I need to upgrade one of the clusters or not.

Answer (score 1):

Geo-replication is compatible between all clusters running the same major version of Pulsar, e.g., 2.x